# What does "spanning files" mean in the help of Manpage?

Tags: man

I open a manpage of some command, and then hit <kbd>h</kbd>.

- In the help, for the search part, what does "spanning files" mean?
- What are "files" refereed to?

I search a pattern, and hit <kbd>n</kbd> to repeat the previous search. I found there is no difference between <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>.

```
                          SEARCHING

  /pattern          *  Search forward for (N-th) matching line.
  ?pattern          *  Search backward for (N-th) matching line.
  n                 *  Repeat previous search (for N-th occurrence).
  N                 *  Repeat previous search in reverse direction.
  ESC-n             *  Repeat previous search, **spanning files**.
  ESC-N             *  Repeat previous search, reverse dir. & **spanning files**.
  ESC-u                Undo (toggle) search highlighting.
  &pattern          *  Display only matching lines
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man` displays man pages using a pager - in your case, `less`.  When you press <kbd>h</kbd>, you're seeing less's help.

So, as for what "spanning files" means, it's referring to searching across multiple files simultaneously opened in `less`.

It doesn't apply to the man page use case (since there's only one file opened at the time), but if you did

```
less file1 file2
```

at the command line, and then searched for a pattern that occurs in both files with `/foo`, you could jump between occurrences of the pattern inside `file1` using <kbd>n</kbd> repeatedly, but it would eventually stop when you hit the last occurrence in the file.  At that point, if you were to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> (or usually also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>) it would jump you to the first occurrence of that pattern in `file2`.